# Prevent Default Link Action in mouseup Event Listener

Tags: jquery, mouseup, onmouseup

I have several jQuery event listener on several links in a matrix (*it's a map parcel selection*).
Now i already prevent the default action on mousedown, but if i prevent the action on mouseup, it doesn't work.
I prevent the default action on mousedown on a link and start "marking" elements from there on. If a "mouseup" occurs in the same Element, the link get's executed.

So what i need to do is prevent link execution in mouseup, but it doesn't work.

```
$('a.parcel').on('mouseup',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This still executes the link that is given in the href of the a element.

Any Ideas anyone?

Comment: @YograjGupta: That didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default action you are preventing on the `mouseup` event is not responsible for changing the href. That being said, it doesn't matter if you prevent it or not, the href gets executed on the `click` event.

The `click` event gets fired after `mousedown`, so changing the `mouseup` to `click` should work just fine.

Comment: I just added an additional on('click',...) Listener that prevents the event. Should have been a no-brainer. Thanks still!

Comment: @AndreschSerj If I understood you correctly, you could do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/RaFFK/show OR multiple links: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/RaFFK/1/show/